# How to align center a label that is inside a header

Tags: html, css, text-align

I have tried white-space:nowrap (in the css) and also I have tried the align="center" like this: `<label align="center">title</label>` But Nothing. Here is my html:
`

```
 <header>
  <img src="Images/logo.png" width="200" heigth="20" alt="Muxa Logo">                
  <label>Generar Pedido de Materia Prima</label>     
 </header>
```

and this is what i have on the css:

```
header{
font-size: 250%;
background: #beb8a4;
}

header img{
width: 200px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 10px;
}    `
```

So this is how it looks like, I just want the title("Generar Pedido de Materia Prima") on the middle

[image]

Also if you can tell me if its a good idea how i put the logo? or maybe it exists a type or special tag for the logo?

Thanks

Comment: `align` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Also, a `label` is probably not the right element here. An `<h1>` would be semantic

Answer (score 0):

The label tag defines a label for an input element. So use a p instead.

If you don't mind using flex box, this will solve your problem.

```css
header {
  font-size: 250%;
  background: #beb8a4;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
header img {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
p {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="Images/logo.png" width="200" heigth="20" alt="Muxa Logo">
  <p>Generar Pedido de Materia Prima</p>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```css
font-size: 70%;
background: #beb8a4;

}
label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2px;
  /*This needs to be modified to fit */
}
header img {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="Images/logo.png" width="200" heigth="20" alt="Muxa Logo">
  <label>Generar Pedido de Materia Prima</label>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r08L0m02/

Answer (score 0):

label is an inline element to center it you need to do a text-align on its parent node, if you want to keep the image on the left and only center the text, here is one of many solutions.
also would recommend using a p tag instead of a label, as label tags are generally used with forms

```css
header{
font-size: 2.5em;
background: #beb8a4;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
}

header img{
float:left;
width: 200px;
height:120px;
margin:20px;
}  
header label{
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:140px;
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="Images/logo.png" width="200" heigth="20" alt="Muxa Logo">                
  <label>Generar Pedido de Materia Prima</label>     
 </header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9vt2g535/

Answer (score 0):

> Setting margin is not a good approach near to me.Well has different
>   effect on each screen according to its size.

And

> secondly,Using image in Brand Name or logo ( words of  common font
>   families) when you can write and style it using css is not good
>   idea.Write logo or brand name and try styling this is easy one you can
>   style it easily.

Here is an idea to make your work done.
 you should use

```
<div id="toMakeInline">
    <div>Your picture or title here with all applied styles like font family
          and font size etc
     </div>
     <div><!--Here that label you want to show--></div>
</div>
```

now style the div to get in line

```
#toMakeInline{
       display:inline;
}
```

that will work for your idea perfectly.I am taking id to target specific div not the all ones.Well you can take only two of them one for title and one for slogan and then give them calss and make their display inline.

```
    <div class="toMakeInline">Your picture or title here with all applied styles like font family
          and font size etc
     </div>
     <div class="toMakeInline"><!--Here that label you want to show--></div>

     #toMakeInline{
        display:inline;
      }
```

Comment: :P i spend my 45minute to give the answer